# React js. Перезагрузка свойства элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

начал изучать React js. Сделал компонент, чтобы он выводился и чтобы при вводе в инпут у меня запускалась функция js.

Код:

```
class Lable extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
    <input
      type="text"
      id={this.props.id}
      placeholder="&nbsp;"
      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
);
}
handleChange(e) {
  this.props.onSearch(e.target.id);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<p className="inp">
  <label>
  <Lable name="1" id="roadFrom" onSearch={search} />
  <span className="label" />
  <span className="border" />
  </label>
</p>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

И кусок кода функции search, она выполняет автозаполнение импута, то есть, ввожу первые буквы и она выводит список и тд, живой поиск.

```
function search(name) {
var field = document.getElementById(name);
var classInactive = "sf_inactive";
var classActive = "sf_active";
var classText = "sf_text";
var classSuggestion = "sf_suggestion";

field.c = field.className;
field.className = field.c + " " + classInactive;
field.onfocus = function() {      
  this.className = this.c + " " + classActive;
  this.value = this.value == "" ? "" : this.value;
};
field.onblur = function() {
  this.className =
    this.value != ""
      ? this.c + " " + classText
      : this.c + " " + classInactive;
  this.value = this.value != "" ? this.value : "";
  clearList();
};
if (suggestion) {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  field.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.style.display = "none";
  div.className = classSuggestion;
  list.style.width = field.offsetWidth + "px";
  div.appendChild(list);
  field.parentNode.appendChild(div);
 }
```

Я ее естественно сократил, чтобы не захламлять.
У меня проблема в том, что при вводе символа в инпут у меня список выпадает, класс к инпуту "sf_inactive" клеится, но когда я ввожу второй символ, у меня div не перезаписывается а приклеивается новый снизу, естественно у  меня за новым списком висит старый и класс "sf_inactive" снова клеится к инпуту

Вот что получается:

```
<input type="text" id="roadFrom" placeholder="&nbsp;" class=" sf_inactive sf_inactive sf_inactive sf_text" autocomplete="off">
```

Вот у меня тут аж три раза sf_inactive sf_inactive sf_inactive, так как три зара клацал на кнопку и приклеено три div'a

```
<div class="sf_suggestion"><ul tabindex="-1" style="display: block; width: 
280px;"><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sfsf</a></li></ul></div>
<div class="sf_suggestion"><ul tabindex="-1" style="display: block; width: 
280px;"><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sfsf</a></li></ul></div>
<div class="sf_suggestion"><ul tabindex="-1" style="display: block; width: 
280px;"><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sfsf</a></li></ul></div>
```

Если это делать не через react, а просто на странице, то все работает корректно, добавляется один класс, и один див, который постоянно меняется.

Как в react это можно исправить? :(

Comment: Вообще непонятно зачем вам реакт, если он является тупо обёрткой над инпутом, а основной код выполняется "вне" реакта и оперирует элементами dom древа напрямую через `appendChild`. Так вот, элемент новый вы создаёте, а в каком месте удаляется старый?

Comment: Это чисто для обучения, чтобы понять суть react. Сам див очищается ниже, я не вывел это, та очищается список. Просто вопрос в том, почему он ниже дива клеит новый в react’е? Это какое-то особое поведение реакта? Или как? Или надо как то перезашружать его после каждого нажатия клавиши.

Comment: *Перед каждым нажатием очистить и потом сразу же добавить новый. В идеале хранить данные подсказки в состоянии и изменять состояние после каждого нажатия. Проблема не в реакте, а функции `search`

Comment: Ну вот я так и думаю, что придется очищать перед. А вообще само по себе почему такое поведение непонятно? Почему он добавляет свойство повторно и новый див? Без реакта работает короектно. В ссылку на кодпен есть

Comment: @MishaSaidov я понял в чем дело, в React когда я нажимаю на клавишу, js скрипт начинает работать заново. А если просто на элементе его вызывать, то он запускается и работает уже внутренняя часть, позволяя вводить данные загружая ответ. Это я console.log поставил в начало, и в react она выполнялась при каждом нажатие

Comment: В вашей имплантации может быть всё что угодно, и не в реакте дело. Вы не правильно с ним работаете, а следовательно не поймёте его принципы.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach что значит не правильно работаю? В общем думаю проще реализацию на js сделать, просто мне эту форму выдавать на 10 разных кнопках надо, что плодит код, хотел вот попробовать и еще прикрутить react, так как хочу в нем разобраться)

Comment: Во первых смешивая реакт, работающий на virtual DOM, с кодом на работающим с DOM напрямую Вы сделаете только хуже и уж точно не поймете реакт. Во вторых модульность Вы не получите таким образом потому что реакт работает используя собственный движок с собственными хуками в отличие от чистого js на сайте.

Comment: Спасибо :) в общем буду более глубже читать, и пробовать вс ена отдельных примерах. Тема -то интересная и как я вижу востребованная. Все таки сделал, чтобы работало все корректно, подкрутил сам js скрипт, но это чушь получилась конечно из условий

Comment: Чтобы правильно инджектить чистый js/jQuery в реакт нужно как минимум понимать что ты делаешь и как это работает. Чтобы инджектить наоборот, ну я не знаю, нужно быть гуру и иметь такой edge case, который я представить не могу

Comment: Пробуйте поднимать проект на реакте и работать там, так Вы сможете освоится и всё понять. Начните с *create-react-app*

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Спасибо большое. Я сам -то и java-backrend разработчик, просто жизнь заставила начинать осваивать js и параллельно решил еще react.